# "You are right; I'm sorry" — semicolon or comma?

Tags: punctuation, commas, semicolons

> - You are right; I'm sorry.
> - You are right, I'm sorry.

Do we use the semicolon or comma? A full stop works. Two independent clauses so perhaps the semicolon should be used.

Comment: All are acceptable, though the meaning may be subtly different in each case.

Comment: Is the second a comma splice?

Comment: Not if that's meant. It could mean *You are right that I am sorry.* (Apparently, not what you meant).

Comment: It's probably more common to omit the "I'm" in the written version of the exclamative: "You are right. _Sorry_. / _Apologies_."

Comment: Using a comma instead of a semicolon is nowhere near the crime that is using a [hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen) instead of a [dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash).

Answer (score 2):

You are right; the semicolon should be deployed here. I don't like the comma splice, although some will argue that it is harmless and conventional in short informal English constructions like your example. A semicolon would be pedantic when the first "sentence" is reduced to one word: "Yes, it is" or "Thanks, I will". For two words, I prefer a semicolon. A hard case would be when the two words are so familiar as to be virtually one: "Thank you; I will" or ""Thank you, I will"? The pedant in me would prefer the former but not be offended by the latter.